# How to avoid Chrome Keep and Discard using selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, ado

I tried all the solutions provided on the internet, But no luck. Any solution will be appreciated:

I am able to resolve this issue via Sikuli only. But as I run my framework in ADO and ADO doesn't support Sikuli. That's why I need a solution without using third party tool.

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Browser_Files/chromedriver.exe");

```
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\DownloadFiles");
        chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
        chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
        _chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

Comment: I hope this can help you [Link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). You have to create a profile with these settings and load while executing the script.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, I just can't understand the question.

Comment: How to handle 'Keep' and 'Discard' option while download files in chrome using Selenium. I tried all options provided on the internet. above one is one of them by creating a chrome profile. @PeterQuan